# AWS CDK DockerImageAsset with buildSsh socket sometimes fails

Tags: docker, ssh, aws-cdk

I am deploying a stack with AWS CDK. I need to access a private github repository and I use the `buildSsh` property when defining a `DockerImageAsset`, to pass my SSH socket to the build environment. It usually works, but sometimes not. I do not see any difference when it fails. When cloning or building locally (e.g. passing the ssh credentials to Docker from the command line), it works.

I realise that there I am giving little information, so my question is more about what I should investigate to provide more.

### Details

#### Code

I am passing the SSH socket to the builder in this way:

```js
// lib/cdk-stack.js

import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as ecrAssets from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr-assets';
import * as ecrDeploy from 'cdk-ecr-deployment';

// ...

export class CdkJsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // ...

    const asset = new ecrAssets.DockerImageAsset(this, id + '-DockerImage', {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, '..'),
      networkMode: ecrAssets.NetworkMode.HOST,
      buildSsh: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK, // pass the SSH agent socket here
      invalidation: {
        buildArgs: false,
      },
    });

    new ecrDeploy.ECRDeployment(this, id + '-DeployDockerImage', {
      src: new ecrDeploy.DockerImageName(asset.imageUri),
      dest: new ecrDeploy.DockerImageName(repository.repositoryUri),
    });



    // ...

}
```

And the relevant lines in my Dockerfile are

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install -r requirements.txt
```

#### Errors

```
#9 [stage-0 5/9] RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install -r requirements.txt
#9 1.498 Collecting data_interface@ git+ssh://git@github.com/.../data_interface.py.git@... (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
#9 1.498   Cloning ssh://****@github.com/.../data_interface.py.git (to revision ...) to /tmp/pip-install-jf3sh2f8/data-interface_...
#9 1.500   Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'ssh://****@github.com/.../data_interface.py.git' /tmp/pip-install-jf3sh2f8/data-interface_...
#9 2.215   git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
#9 2.215   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#9 2.216 
#9 2.216   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#9 2.217   and the repository exists.
#9 2.225   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 2.225   
#9 2.225   × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'ssh://****@github.com/.../data_interface.py.git' /tmp/pip-install-jf3sh2f8/data-interface_... did not run successfully.
#9 2.225   │ exit code: 128
#9 2.225   ╰─> See above for output.
#9 2.225   
#9 2.225   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#9 2.226 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 2.226 
#9 2.226 × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'ssh://****@github.com/.../data_interface.py.git' /tmp/pip-install-jf3sh2f8/data-interface_... did not run successfully.
#9 2.226 │ exit code: 128
#9 2.226 ╰─> See above for output.
#9 2.226 
#9 2.226 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#9 2.464 
#9 2.464 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
#9 2.464 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
#9 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

#### Behaviour

The failure usually lasts for a while, then works again; it is not intermittent.